# What is the best way to print a table with delimiters in Python

Tags: python, coding-style

I want to print a table mixed with string and float values, as tab delimited output printout. Sure I can get the job done:

```
>>> tab = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
>>> for row in tab:
...     out = ""
...     for col in row:
...             out = out + str(col) + "\t"
...     print out.rstrip()
... 
a   1
b   2
```

But I have a feeling there is a better way to do it in Python, at least to print each row with specified delimiter, if not the whole table. Little googling (from [here](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)) and it is already shorter:

```
>>> for row in tab:
...     print "\t".join([str(col) for col in row])
... 
a   1
b   2
```

Is there still a better, or more Python-ish, way to do it?

Comment: In recent python (2.5+ I think) you can drop the [] from that join: '\t'.join(str(col) for col in row) -- this is a generator expression and avoids creating the intermediate list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your shorter solution would work well as something quick and dirty.  But if you need to handle large amounts of data, it'd be better to use `csv` module:

```
import sys, csv
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter="\t")
writer.writerows(data)
```

The benefit of this solution is that you may easily customize all aspects of output format: delimiter, quotation, column headers, escape sequences...

Comment: As it stands though, that solution will probably do many things you wouldn't expect.  It will double-up quotes in your input, for example.  Embedded quotes are treated by "quoting" the whole string, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: (continued) If all that is desired is simple tab delmited data, with no danger of embedded tabs, the basic approach is probably easier to get right, rather than figuring the appropriate dialect to use with the csv module.

Comment: Excellent, cvs was exactly what I was looking for. I need to go through documentation, but I think the things I would not expect may very well be what I want anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's going to get much better than your second code snippet... maybe, if you really want,

```
print "\n".join("\t".join(str(col) for col in row) for row in tab)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import csv

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
tab = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
writer.writerows(tab)
```

Comment: `dialect` should be either `'excel-tab'` or `csv.excel_tab` but not `'csv.excel_tab'`

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use concatanation because it creates a new string every time. cStringIO.StringIO will do this kind of job much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *why* you want to output like that, but if you just want to visually reference the data you might want to try the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) module.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> for item in tab:
...     pprint.pprint(item, indent=4, depth=2)
...
['a', 1]
['b', 2]
>>>
>>> pprint.pprint(tab, indent=4, width=1, depth=2)
[   [   'a',
        1],
    [   'b',
        2]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [prettytable](https://code.google.com/archive/p/prettytable/) library may be useful. It also helps maintain the column alignment and allows additional style customizations.

**Example:**

```
# Ref: https://code.google.com/archive/p/prettytable/

import prettytable

# Read the input csv file
with open("input.csv", "r") as input_file:
    table = prettytable.from_csv(input_file)

# Optionally, change the default style
table.set_style(prettytable.PLAIN_COLUMNS)
table.align = "l"
table.valign = "t"

# Write the output ASCII text file
with open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    print("{}".format(table.get_string()), file=output_file)

# Optionally, write the output html file
with open("output.html", "w") as output_file:
    print("{}".format(table.get_html_string()), file=output_file)
```