# Was asked to make a simple Windchill index table

Tags: python

> A positive whole number n > 2 is primed if no number between 2 and the square root of n (inclusive) evenly divides n. Write a program that accepts a value of n as input and determines if the value is prime. If n is not prime, your program should quit as soon as it finds a value that evenly divides n.

i have the basics written for this one.

```
def main():
n = input(Please enter your number:")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't  `return` anything in your `windspeed()` function, only assign the result to X.

Change your function to:

```
def windspeed (t,v):
    return 35.74 + 0.6215*t - 35.75*(v**0.16) + 0.4275*t*(v**0.16)
```

Furthermore, you want to modify the printing of your table - the current code produces a malformatted one. Something like this:

```
table = list()
for t in temperatures:
     row = list()
     row.append(t)
     for v in windspeeds:
          row.append(windspeed(t, v))
     table.append(row)

print (4*" "+" ".join("%3d" % _ for _ in windspeeds))
print("\n".join(" ".join("%3d" % col for col in row) for row in table))
```

For more examples [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583557/what-is-the-best-way-to-print-a-table-with-delimiters-in-python)

Comment: that does indeed stop the error, but then my table begins to look like this:      0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50 
-20 
-10 
  0 
 10 
 20 
 30 
 40 
 50 
 60 
 73  59  58  57  56  56  55  55  54  54  54            how do i then format the table correctly? im sorry if i sound dumb, im just lost on hwo to fix this program right now

Comment: ok, well that didnt show up correctly, well in words, it stops the errors, but then it will do the headings correctly, but then only print the 73 59 58 57 56 56 55 55 54 54 54 line under where the 60 is, so it doesnt complete it as a table, where am i going wrong?

Comment: i know see what i did wrong, thank you, this will go a far way in making sure i format my tables correctly from now on